# How to create a folder in C:\ so that it has the same shortname as "C:\Program Files" would?

Tags: windows, ntfs

Shortnames in NTFS is a compatibility feature for DOS systems which only support 8.3 file names (<8 character name>.<3 character extension>). We can get the shortnames of a files/folders in the current directory with `dir /x`.

"C:\Program Files" has the shortname "PROGRA~1". What should a folder be named so that it becomes "PROGRA~1" and "C:\Program Files" becomes "PROGRA~2"?

I tried "Program Filas", "Program Fil", "Program File" to no avail. I also tried setting the creation, modification, lastwrite times to something older with:

```
$(Get-Item "Program Filas").creationtime=$(Get-Date "01/01/2000 00:01 am")
$(Get-Item "Program Filas").lastaccesstime=$(Get-Date "01/01/2000 00:01 am")
$(Get-Item "Program Filas").lastwritetime=$(Get-Date "01/01/2000 00:01 am")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will never become `PROGRA~1` as long as you already have another directory named that.

Short names are **persistent** – they're chosen when creating the object and stored within the filesystem just like regular names. Once the name has been assigned, neither alphabetical order nor modification timestamps will cause it to change. (After all, they're supposed to *work* like regular names, which includes not having the name suddenly change on its own.)

The Win32 API has a function [SetFileShortName()](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-setfileshortnamew) which lets you directly change the 8.3 names of any path, so write a short program (or use Python ctypes, etc) to perform this change.

(After changing the short name of "Program Files" to something custom, you can create a directory literally named `PROGRA~1` if that's what the program needs. You don't need to craft a special name to trick the algorithm.)

Alternatively, you could rename "Program Files" to "asdf", freeing up its short name. Then, once "PROGRA~1" is claimed by your directory, rename the real one back to "Program Files" and it'll be assigned ~2.